# Angular 6 internationalisation that changes directions

Tags: angular, web, internationalization, frontend, translate

I am working on a website using Angular 6 that should be presented in English and in Arabic, the problem is that these two languages are written on the opposite sides which the Angular Translate does not provide!
Any help ?

Comment: Look into RTL..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something you can solve just with CSS by using the `direction` property. When you detect the language change you can apply `direction: rtl` to the body of your HTML.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction